# ObjC: how to insert component to url from A/B to A/between/B?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, url, nsstring

I need to manipulate some URL in term of adding component to it in this way:

> /img/david/PlayBasketball.jpg

will become:

> /img/HiRes/david/PlayBasketball.jpg

in Objective C for iPhone, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) methods `pathComponents` and `pathWithComponents`:

```
NSString *p = @"/img/david/PlayBasketball.jpg";

NSMutableArray *cmps = [NSMutableArray arrayWitharray:[p pathComponents]];
// cmps will be: ["/", "img", "david", "PlayBasketball.jpg"]

[cmps insertObject:@"HIRes" atIndex:2];
// You want index 2 because "/" is at index 0, and "img" is at index 1.

NSString *newPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:cmps];
// The pathWithComponents method will add the rest of the "/"'s for you
```

Now, `newPath` will be: `@"/img/HiRes/david/PlayBasketball.jpg"`.